# How to delete multiple records from Publication list in SFMC - Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, contact-deletion

There is script available delete one record at a time. How to delete multiple records?

```javascript
<script runat="server">    
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var subkey = "your sub key"
var email = "email address"
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var sub = {
        SubscriberKey: subkey,
        EmailAddress: email,
        Lists: [{
            ID: "list id"
               }]
         };

var resp = prox.deleteItem("Subscriber", sub);

Write("Response: " + Stringify(resp));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pretty much the same code, you just make `sub` an array of objects instead of a single object and then use `deleteBatch` instead of `deleteItem` (**[ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_delete.htm)**).

```javascript
<script runat="server">    
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var subkey = "<guid>"
var email = "email@example.com"
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var sub = [
        {
        SubscriberKey: subkey,
        EmailAddress: email,
        Lists: [{
            ID: "123"
               }]
         },
         {
        SubscriberKey: subkey2,
        EmailAddress: email2,
        Lists: [{
            ID: "123"
               }]
         }
    ]

var resp = prox.deleteBatch("Subscriber", sub);

Write("Response: " + Stringify(resp));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to delete multiple records only from All Subscriber list?

Comment: I would recommend using Contact Delete instead for those. This is a pretty decent walkthrough on setting this up programmatically using REST API: https://code4.cloud/articles/sfmc-automate-delete-contacts-process-with-rest-api/

Comment: I need to delete 20K records only from publication list. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This is my script to update the Publication List using bulk update (DE)

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
// Set specific BU context if required
prox.setClientId({ "ID": XXXXX}); //MID Number
 
    var b1 = DataExtension.Init(PublicationList_BulkUpdate"); 
    var data = b1.Rows.Lookup(["isActive"], ["False"]);  //Value FALSE to unsubscribe from PublicationList
    if(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
            var status; 
            var subkey = data[i]["SubscriberKey"]; 
            var sub = { SubscriberKey: subkey, Status: 'Active', Lists: [{ ID: 'PUBID', Status: 'unsubscribed' }] }; //Update Status to be unsubscribed and specified the PublicationID
            var options = { SaveOptions: [{PropertyName: "*",SaveAction: "delete"}]};
            var resp = prox.updateItem("Subscriber", sub, options);
            status = status=="OK"? status + '. Updated.' : status; 
        }    
    } else {
        status = "Blank SubscriberKey";
    }
    //Write("Response: " + Stringify(resp));

</script>
```

Hopefully can help your question

Comment: Is the question not about deletions instead of updates? So how is your script interesting in the context of deletions?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! I agree with Felix: This may be a valid bulk update script, but can it be translated to a bulk delete script? (I don't know that answer, as I am not very familiar with SFMC.) If it can, please edit your answer to make it show bulk deletion; if it cannot, please remove your answer. SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum, so we try to keep the answers completely relevant to the associated question.